# $\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-p^2} = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let the following series be given:

$$
\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-p^2}
$$

It is easy to see that:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-p^2} \\ =
&\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-p)(n+p)}
\end{align}

But does this tell anything about the limit of this series?

Comment: the sum containes a function which is non elelementar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: You can write:
$$\frac{1}{(n-p)(n+p)} = \frac{1}{2p}\big(\frac{1}{n-p}-\frac{1}{n+p}\big)$$

Comment: And if this is unclear, expand the sum out a few terms and cancel of terms.

Comment: (+1) I also approached in a similar way but the final answer comes out to be $$\frac{1}{2p}\sum_{i=1}^{2p}{\frac{1}{i}}$$ which I am not able to express in terms of any elementary function, hence I thought if there was any elementary function which does so.

Comment: @user350331 There is no elementary way to write the harmonic series.

Comment: @user350331 but that's a finite sum and is elementary itself, isn't it?

Comment: @ZainPatel It is a sum of elementary functions, but there is no closed way to write it using elementary functions. (i.e., no way to write it without a sum/product of some sort)

Comment: @Omry so do you think that $n^2 + n$ isn't elementary because it's the sum (or product) of two things?

Comment: @ZainPatel No, since you have a closed expression for it. You do not need $\Sigma$.

Comment: @Omry If you wish, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\ dx=-(n+1)\int_0^1x^n\ln(1-x)\ dx=\psi(n+1)+\gamma$$

Comment: @Omry so I can write this as $\frac{1}{2p}( 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/2p)$ no sigma. It's a *finite* sum.

Comment: @ZainPatel What kind of elementary function allows the amount of terms you add together to be changing?!